# R sort string by number inside

Tags: r, string, sorting

I have a list of file names to be open. the format is like below.

```
'xxxxx_xxxxxx 00.02.xls'
```

first 00 refers to year, second 02 refers to month.

Is there anyway to sort this list first with year index, than month index.

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler the language is R (from the tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the amount of characters may change in the filename, a regex may be able to locate the year and month for you. I like `str_match` from the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)
extract <- str_match(vec, "([0-9]{2})\\.([0-9]{2}).xls")
vec[order(rank(extract[,2]))]
```

That way, if you decided that you wanted to one day order it by month, you could change the last line from `2` into `3`.

If you want the years descending, add `rev` to it. Like this, `vec[rev(order(rank(extract[,2])))]`

The great thing about `str_match` is that it tells you what it matched and creates columns for the tokens that you put in the parantheses. You can then subset those columns like any other data frame.

```
extract
     [,1]        [,2] [,3]
[1,] "07.02.xls" "07" "02"
[2,] "15.12.xls" "15" "12"
[3,] "01.02.xls" "01" "02"
```

## Example

```
vec <- c("xxxxxxxx_xxxxxx 07.02.xls", "xxxxx_xxx 15.12.xls", "xxxxx_xxxxxx 01.02.xls")
extract <- str_match(vec, "([0-9]{2})\\.([0-9]{2}).xls")
vec[order(rank(extract[,2]))]
[1] "xxxxx_xxxxxx 01.02.xls"    "xxxxxxxx_xxxxxx 07.02.xls" "xxxxx_xxx 15.12.xls" 

#or reversed

vec[rev(order(rank(extract[,2])))]
[1] "xxxxx_xxx 15.12.xls"       "xxxxxxxx_xxxxxx 07.02.xls" "xxxxx_xxxxxx 01.02.xls"
```

Answer (score 3):

If there are always 13 characters before the two year digits, then you can do this (assuming your vector of file names is called `x`):

```
x[order(substr(x,14,18))]
```

Comment: Brilliant! I will remember this in future...but in my case the length of the file name may change...

Comment: You also use a regex inside of `order`, which is essentially a variation on @plafort's answer. For example: `x[order(gsub("(\\d{2}.\\d{2})","\\1", x))]`.

Comment: Forgot to remove the unnecessary parts of the string. Thanks for catching. Should be `x[order(gsub(".*(\\d{2}.\\d{2}).*","\\1", x))]`.